# Optimize the code for one command with only one different parameter

Tags: arcpy, spatial-join, list

I am not too familiar with ArcPy/Python, but since some commands are only available in ArcGIS, I try to implement my idea using ArcPy. I want to use a command several times, but each time only with a small change of a variable (distance) and the resulting output name.

```
arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis(outSP, outSP, inLAS[:-4] + '_D100.shp', "JOIN_ONE_TO_ONE", "KEEP_ALL","#", "WITHIN_A_DISTANCE_3D", "10 Meters", "DIST_100")
arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis(outSP, outSP, inLAS[:-4] + '_D050.shp', "JOIN_ONE_TO_ONE", "KEEP_ALL","#", "WITHIN_A_DISTANCE_3D", "5 Meters", "DIST_050")
arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis(outSP, outSP, inLAS[:-4] + '_D040.shp', "JOIN_ONE_TO_ONE", "KEEP_ALL","#", "WITHIN_A_DISTANCE_3D", "4 Meters", "DIST_040")
arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis(outSP, outSP, inLAS[:-4] + '_D030.shp', "JOIN_ONE_TO_ONE", "KEEP_ALL","#", "WITHIN_A_DISTANCE_3D", "3 Meters", "DIST_030")
arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis(outSP, outSP, inLAS[:-4] + '_D020.shp', "JOIN_ONE_TO_ONE", "KEEP_ALL","#", "WITHIN_A_DISTANCE_3D", "2 Meters", "DIST_020")
arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis(outSP, outSP, inLAS[:-4] + '_D010.shp', "JOIN_ONE_TO_ONE", "KEEP_ALL","#", "WITHIN_A_DISTANCE_3D", "1 Meters", "DIST_010")
arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis(outSP, outSP, inLAS[:-4] + '_D005.shp', "JOIN_ONE_TO_ONE", "KEEP_ALL","#", "WITHIN_A_DISTANCE_3D", "0.5 Meters", "DIST_005")
```

Since this does not look very nice in the code, I would like to optimize/compact the code. My idea was to do this with a list:

```
dist_list = (0.5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10)
    for n in dist_list:
    expression = "outSP, outSP, inLAS[:-4] + '_D' + str(int(n * 10) + '.shp', 'JOIN_ONE_TO_ONE', 'KEEP_ALL','#', 'WITHIN_A_DISTANCE_3D', n ' Meters', 'DIST_' + int(n * 10)"
```

Unfortunately I only get error messages that my command is not correct. I suppose it is related to the composition of the expression in which I combine the list items with the remaining strings.

I multiply the list item by 10 so that I don't get a second dot in the file name.

Is there someone who can tell me how to fix this problem?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Please remember to always include the exact error message in the question.

Answer (score 1):

`expression` is a string that spatial join will not understand. It wants comma separated parameters.

Replace `expression =` with `arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis(` and remove the double quotes in the beginning and end. You should include the parameter names to be sure you are providing the correct one in correct place, for example `target_features=`

```
dist_list = (0.5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10) #btw (1,2,3) is a tuple, list: [1,2,3]. Does not matter in this case though.
for n in dist_list:
    arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis(target_features=outSP, join_features=outSP,...
```